# How To Create New Vertex or Segment When Extrude Passing or Intersection Other Object or Shape

Tags: extrude

I am creating a computer table , To make the partition board (where the keyboard is kept). I added in two loop cuts on either leg and extruded the face formed by the loop cut as shown:
[image]

It is known that it can't make new vertex, edges, and faces when the extruded face passing through it. In short it can't merge with the middle leg.

[image]

In the left leg it has 3 face for each direction,  but the middle leg (since it don't have any loop cuts) still have only 1 face for each direction.(See the image)

[image]

Of course, the face or vertices count doesn't matter for the viewers of the final render...But for basic concept or fundamental, I think it's wrong??

So I hope you can help me to doing it *right and clean*.
Can you please point out what should I do. (if direct extrude is not recommended)

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Nxdhin has give you a nice answer.. (You might want to click the tick it to mark it as accepted).. I just want to make one suggestion .. often, for realism and practicality, it's preferable to model separate parts in life as separate parts in the model. In which case you would Shift-D duplicate the faces, before bridging them.

Comment: Dear @RobinBetts I have click "this answer is useful" for both people. but I didn't find button "mark it as accepted" nor something like "close this tread because i have get the answer". where should i click or do for next to close this tread?

and thanks for the tips, I will keep in my mind, I'm doing like those is to broaden my basic knowledge.

Comment: As @Robin bets said we mostly use different mesh to make such parts. That's reduces the time consumption.

Comment: thanks @Nxdhin2005 I didn't aware those button before. and thanks again for your help. :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The easiest way to do it is by [*Bridging the Edge Loops*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bridge_edge_loops.html).

- Make two legs for the table:

[image]

- Create two edge loops on both the legs by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Make sure that it's perfectly aligned or else you will get a slope. *To place the loopcuts perfectly hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while sliding the edge loop*. Which will get you this:

[image]

- Now select the faces as shown and press <kbd>F3</kbd> and type in Bridge edge loops.

[image]

[image]

[image]
There you have it.

Comment: thanks for the answer and effort sir. 
I have test it and its work very well.

Bridging the Edge Loops. is very easy to use.

Comment: It's my pleasure . I too learn a lot from such questions.

Answer (score 2):

To do that with the actual selection, you have to use the merge by distance option in in top panel, and select in the options "split edges and faces", and then select that face and the 4 edges in that area, and press <kbd>G</kbd> key to move *(but don't move the mouse, just press it one time, and then left click to release)* and be careful with this option.

It can destroy the topology in unwanted areas, enable it just when you need it, so disable it after you do that and then remove the edges/faces that got cut off and fill any space left with the <kbd>F</kbd> key...

Comment: I have tried it, when I used it, 
it can make 4 new vertex in blue circle in my third pic. 
and make 4 new vertex who facing back.
( I guess it calculate if there are 2 edges intersection then make a new vertex)

but it didn't make edge nor face between new 4 vertex front and new 4 vertex back.
It's ok though, I can do it manually. I think this trick would be handy in next.

thanks for the tips.